Classes for Avro serialization not recognized in converter plugins, using Strimzi to deploy KafkaConnect container
Background:
I want to implement Avro serialization for payload values using Strimzi. Despite loading required plug-ins to the Strimzi KafkaConnect YAML, I encounter an error that classes aren't found when I deploy the connector via API. Has anyone managed to figure this out?
Relevant connector configuration specs:
"value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "<my url>"

KafkaConnect container configuration
build:
    output:
      type: docker
      image: <my image> #
      pushSecret: <my secret> 
    plugins:
      - name: mongodb-connector
        artifacts:
          - type: jar
            url: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/kafka/mongo-kafka-connect/1.5.1/mongo-kafka-connect-1.5.1-all.jar # https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/kafka/mongo-kafka-connect/1.5.0/mongo-kafka-connect-1.5.0-all.jar
          - type: jar
            url: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro/1.10.2/avro-1.10.2.jar
          - type: jar
            url: https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-connect-avro-converter/7.7.1/kafka-connect-avro-converter-7.7.1.jar
          - type: jar
            url: https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-schema-serializer/7.7.1/kafka-schema-serializer-7.7.1.jar
          - type: jar
            url: https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-schema-registry-client/7.7.1/kafka-schema-registry-client-7.7.1.jar
          

KafkaConnect error logs when I deploy the connector:
Failed to start task <task-name> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker) [StartAndStopExecutor-connect-my-connect-cluster-connect-0.my-connect-cluster-connect.kafka-dev.svc:8083-6]
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer**
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.configure(AvroConverter.java:80)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newConverter(Plugins.java:395)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:634)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startSourceTask(Worker.java:560)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:2001)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$getTaskStartingCallable$38(DistributedHerder.java:2018)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer**
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:124)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        ... 20 more


You need kafka-avro-serializer not kafka-schema-serializer
You should've also used Confluent hub cli to download Avro converter and Mongo connector, not use Maven central, as your method doesn't guarantee transitive dependencies
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-avro-serializer/7.7.1
Ideally you precreate the container image as well.

Thanks. Instead of using confluent hub cli, i downloaded the kafka-connect-avro-converter while inspecting the page's network tab, allowing me to retrieve the url of the plugin zip file for my Strimzi YAML file. That worked perfectly.
I'm now encountering errors with the schema registry in Azure Event Hub, and posted another question here about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79245001/connect-to-schema-registry-associated-with-azure-event-hub-from-kafkaconnect-usi

I've not used azure. Please use the check mark next to this post to approve it
